# Trying to upload a Unity/Vuforia project to S7(Oreo 8.0)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've downloaded everything Unity asked me for: Java Development Kit(JDK) and then Android Studio. I set file paths and configured Vuforia as well as the tutorial videos explained. I'm still getting 10 errors:

```
Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultInitializationErrorHandler.cs(101,23): 
  error CS0246: The type or namespace name `VuforiaUnity' could not be found. 
  Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

and

```
Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs(22,15): 
  error CS0246: The type or namespace name `TrackableBehaviour' could not be found. 
  Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

there are others, but they are similar. Please give me any tips you have or ask any other questions on things I may have missed.

Comment: There's something similar reported on Vuforia forums you might want check;  https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/known-issue-after-importing-vuforia-samples-20181-20182 .

Comment: Thank You, and sorry about the formatting, never posted here before!

Comment: So I downloaded the new version, still getting the same error, anything else I might try?